# What to use for an app with an anatomy model?

Tags: frameworks

I want to develop an android application which contains a 3D model. The app will be a pain diary with a 3D model of the human anatomy, which should be able to rotate and zoom in and out. The User should be able to tap on a point or to drag an area on the model to locate his pain

Since I have never made any application like this before I would be glad if you could give me some advice on which frameworks I should consider for this kind of project.

It would be awsome if you could recommend two or three frameworks, because i have to write a paper for this project, in which i have to discuss a few different frameworks.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please looks for unity and provide some more informations about your project.

Comment: Thank you for you advise on unity. I would be glad if you could give me one or two more frameworks which i could use.
more information to the project: It app will be a pain diary with an 3D model of the human anatomy, which should be able to rotate and zoom in and out. The User should be able to tap on a point or to drag an area on the model to locate his pain.

Comment: I understand it now clearly. Check unity it has so much features and documentations. @hannes

Comment: Thank you. Are there any other frameworks you would recommend? Because i have to write paper about the project and i have to discuss which technologies i could use.